# How Can I Change the Background Color of a Label in WPF based on Whether it Equals Another Label?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF coming from Winforms. I have 2 labels; one which pulls a job amount from SQL and the other which pulls the number of items that have been actually run and displaying them in a Datagrid. If the number of items run equals the job amount (job complete) then I want the background of the lblCount control to change to Green/ else Red.

I'm thinking its probably going to be through a trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="Pass" TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=????}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path= ????}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then set it on the control like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lblCount" Content="{Binding ElementName=dgvJob, Path=Items.Count}" Style="{StaticResource Pass}" Grid.Column="5"
```

But I'm not sure how to say in XAML "if its equal to the other label's value". Do I need to create a Property in the code behind and return a value or is there another way?

Comment: In wpf a label is a content control. This ends up with a textblock as content and with the string you set as text when you set content to a string ( as you are doing ). It is more usual in wpf to use a textblock.

Comment: Rather than a multi value converter I would recommend totalling the value and comparing in the viewmodel. Then exposing a plain bool from the viewmodel. Use that as a datatrigger to drive the brush used. This is lower complexity code and you can see the logic to be used there in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a MultiValueConverter and use it in MultiBinding on DataTrigger.

Your MultiValueConverter would look something like this:

```
class StringMatchConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region Public Methods

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!(values[0] as string).Equals(values[i] as string))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```

While your Style would look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
       <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringMatchConverter}">
                               <Binding ElementName="lblCount" Path="Content" />
                               <Binding ElementName="lblItems" Path="Content" />
                         </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Value>True</DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
              </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```